# get data from locked file php

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
// read in the existing file
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("filename.xls");
```

Currently I am using PHPExcel library for importing excel file to database but when file is 
updated and saved, the file goes into locked state, after locked status when I try to 
import file then file is uploaded successfully but the file is blank. I don't get any data in 
uploaded file.

Comment: I provided an answer, though I am not certain if it addresses your question as it is unclear. If it does not, please edit to clarify your question and leave a comment letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to unlock the file before accessing it, you can do so with [flock](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) and the LOCK_UN flag:

```
$file = fopen('filename.xls', 'r');
flock($file, LOCK_UN);
```